# add contextual menu (right click) in Windows XP/7 Explorer to perform actions on file

Tags: windows, menu

I am writing a little application that performs some simple actions on some specific files, in C# at the moment but I wouldn't mind changing.

Ideally, I would like to be able to add a contextual menu on right click **in Windows XP/7 Explorer**, nothing to do with ad hoc **Forms**. There, I'd like to add a couple of options in a tab of the name of my app. Also, I would like to build an .exe that installs my program on the user's machine.

Do you have any ideas/links to suggest ? I'm chancing on dodgy pages while googling, not even getting close to what I want to achieve.

Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointers for writing context menu items for windows explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671865/pointers-for-writing-context-menu-items-for-windows-explorer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need Visual Studio to fulfill all your requirements

1. To Create an installer you need to create Setup & deploy project.
2. Then for `Context menu` & also I think you will use a `notify Icon` too for you context menu item. An easy to use tutorial is http://www.dotnetperls.com/contextmenustrip and also the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) library has lots n lots of documentation.
   There are some good tutorials and few of them that I found very helpful to beginners are
   [Getting Started with Setup Projects](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/), [MSDN Getting Started with Windows Installers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372845%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [MSDN ContextMenuStrip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx), [MSDN Setup & Deploy Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx), [NotifyIcon ContextStrip Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.contextmenu.aspx) Hope this helps! If you find my answer helpful please rate me :)

Comment: What I want is specifically the ability to add an element on the "right-click" menu that pops up when the user right clicks on a file in Windows Explorer

Comment: take a look at this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/08/microsoft-all-in-one-code-framework-new-samples-updated-on-2010-09-06.aspx)